# How to extend Publish Queue Context Menu?

Tags: gui-extensions

I'm writing a GUI extension and trying to add the functionality to the Publishing queue context menu,

In my extension.config I configured the extension this way:

```
 <ext:contextmenus>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension name="MyExtension" assignid="MyExtension" insertbefore="OtherExtension">
              <ext:menudeclaration externaldefinition="">
                <cmenu:ContextMenuItem id="MyExtension" name="Exportar selección a Excel" command="LanzarVentana4"/>
              </ext:menudeclaration>
              <ext:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>Extensiones.MyExtension.Commands</cfg:dependency>
              </ext:dependencies>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="DashboardView"/>
                <ext:view name="DashboardContextMenu"/>
                <ext:view name="PublishQueueView">
                  <ext:control id="PublishQueueContextMenu" />
                </ext:view>
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:contextmenus>
```

But after restarting IIS and cleaning the browser cache the extension still not appearing in the Publish queue context menu.
In the normal context menu is working.

I'd tried also to configure like in this [extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx), but still the icon does not appear in the publish queue context menu.

```
<ext:apply>
          <ext:view name="*">
               <ext:control id="PublishQueueContextMenu" />
          </ext:view>
</ext:apply>
```

Any tips?

Comment: UI Beardcore beat me to it :D But about the icon not showing up: keep in mind that the theme has changed to 'Carbon2' since that extension was released. So you will want to put your icon in Themes/Carbon2 instead of Themes/Carbon (although some customers might have reverted to the old theme, so ideally you will probably both versions)

Comment: The extension works fine. Thanks! I've foud the problem is on my config file, with the "insertbefore" element. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<ext:apply>
    <ext:view name="publishqueuepopup">
        <ext:control id="PublishQueueContextMenu" />
    </ext:view>
</ext:apply>
```

Comment: That works. But the real problem was with my extension.config file. In this line: <ext:extension name="ExportarExcel" assignid="ExportarExcel" insertbefore="OtherExtension">   Using "cm_whereused" instead of "OtherExtension" solved the problem, "OtherExtension" is an extension wich isn't included in the Queue context menu. Was my fault :P